# I can't bring the section under the header tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this page: [page](https://product-landing-page.freecodecamp.rocks/)
But the header and the section part overlap. I can get it down by adding padding-top: 75px but I'm not sure if that's correct. What is the right thing to do to fix this?
And in the navbar in the example, the space between the list items is more than mine, but I gave the same padding. What is the problem?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #eee;
}

html,body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 75px;;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.logo{
    width: 60vw;
}
.logo > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;;
}

nav > ul{
    width: 35vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="" class="header-img">
        </div>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#how_it_works" class="nav-link">How It Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="hero">
        <h2>Hadcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
        <form action="" id="form">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">

        </form>
    </section>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use fix for inner div not the outer div
As you have given position fixed to navbar, just give it :

```
Position:absolute;
```

And make innner div in it then give this div position relative

```
Position:fixed;
```

Comment: I couldnt get what should I do :(